# Sub-components not taking 100% of space (Angular Material Tab)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, css-grid

I need sub-components of the angular tabs to take 100% of the space given (with 20% blank portions on the sides. I was able to get it working, please see this stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-custom-tabs-3gdeu4

The hierarchy is as follows:

```
AppComponent
    ----> TabComponent (inside AppComponent)
            ----> ComponentA (inside TabComponent)
```

To get this to work, I made the `body` of `index.html` have a height of `100vh` (see `styles.css`)

What I don't understand is why the `tab.component.css` and `component-a.component.css` then need to have a height of 100% set as well? (if it's removed from either it stops taking the whole space)

Isn't the whole point of using the `host:` with `display: grid` that the sub-component will automatically take 100% of what is given to it? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS grid layout works by resizing all *direct* children of an element with `display: grid`. Sub-children are not resized. So your `<app-tab>` will only resize its single direct child `<mat-tab-group>`, and your `<app-component-a>` will only resize its single direct child `<span class="test">`. Those are the only places where you've applied grid layout. As you've discovered, this won't achieve what you want so you've had to resort to other methods.